# R efficient index matching elements, cluster evaluation

Tags: r, indexing, cluster-analysis

This may be a fairly esoteric question.

I'm trying to implement some of the ideas from Albatineh et al (2006) (DOI: 10.1007/s00357-006-0017-z) for a spatial clustering algorithm.  The basic idea is one way to assess the stability of a clustering result is to examine how often pairs of observations end up in the same class.  In a well defined solution pairs of observations should frequently end up in the same group.

The challenge is that in a large data set there are n^2 possible pairs (and most don't occur).  We have structured our output as follows:

```
A  B  C  C  A
B  A  A  A  B
A  B  C  C  A
```

Where the column index is the observation ID and each row represents a run from the clustering algorithm.  In this example there are 5 observations and the algorithm was run 3 times.  The cluster labels A:C are essentially arbitrary between runs. I'd like an efficient way to calculate something like this:

```
ID1 ID2 
1    5
2   
3    4
4    3
5    1
1    2
2    3
2    4
...
```

This accomplishes my goal but is *super* slow, especially for a large data frame:

```
testData <- matrix(data=sample(x=c("A", "B", "C"), 15, replace=TRUE), nrow=3)

cluPr <- function(pr.obs){
    pairs <- data.frame()
    for (row in 1:dim(pr.obs)[1]){
        for (ob in 1:dim(pr.obs)[2]){
            ob.pairs <- which(pr.obs[row,] %in% pr.obs[row,ob], arr.ind=TRUE)
            pairs <- rbind(pairs, cbind(ob, ob.pairs))
        }

    }
    return(pairs)   
}

cluPr(testData)
```

Comment: Maybe because , I am not a clustering proficient , but here re-reading the OP many times i can't get what are you asking about. I am really confused.

Comment: I've added some code to clarify.

Comment: Hi @GeoSS, could you please consider accepting one of the answers below if you believe your question is satisfactorily answered? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively quick approach using the `combn()` function.  I assumed that the name of your matrix was `m`.

```
results <- t(combn(dim(m)[2], 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], sum(m[, x[1]] == m[, x[2]]))))
results2 <- results[results[, 3]>0, ]
```

Comment: This is really helpful but is still slow:<br/>  > m <- reg.trt[1,]
> results <- t(combn(dim(m)[2], 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], sum(m[, x[1]] == m[, x[2]]))))
> system.time(results <- t(combn(dim(m)[2], 2, function(x) c(x[1], x[2], sum(m[, x[1]] == m[, x[2]])))))
   user  system elapsed 
 42.698   0.176  42.527 
> system.time(cluPr(reg.trt[1,]))
   user  system elapsed 
 23.376   0.120  23.368

Comment: Sorry about the formatting in the comment.  This is really helpful but this takes about 40 seconds to process a single row of about 1000 observations (IDs).

Comment: Is that the typical dimension you are working with?  I compared speeds using a 30 row by 50 column matrix and the `combn()` function was much faster.  `> system.time(cluPr(testData))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.98    0.02    3.99 
> system.time(new(testData))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01 `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
clu.pairs <- function(k, row)
{
    w <- which(row==k)

    expand.grid(w, w)
}

row.pairs <- function(row)
{
    do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(row), function(k) clu.pairs(k, row)))
}

full.pairs <- function(data)
{
    do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(nrow(data)), function(i) row.pairs(data[i,])))
}
```

And use `full.pairs(testData)`. The result is not in the same order as yours, but it's equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

My first implementation (*not* in R; my code is much faster in Java) of the pair counting metrics was with ordered generators, and then doing a merge-sort way of computing the intersection. It was still on the order of `O(n^2)` run-time, but much lower in memory use.

However, you need to realize that you *don't* need to know the exact pairs. You only need the quantity in the intersections, and that can be computed straightforward from the *intersection matrix*, just like most other similarity measures. It's substantially faster if you only need to compute the set intersection sizes; with hash tables, set intersection should be in `O(n)`.

I don't have time to look it up; but we may have touched this in the discussion of

> *Evaluation of Clusterings – Metrics and Visual Support*
>
> Data Engineering (ICDE), 2012 IEEE 28th International Conference on
>
> Elke Achtert, Sascha Goldhofer, Hans-Peter Kriegel, Erich Schubert, Arthur Zimek

where we demonstrated a visual tool to explore the pair-counting based measures, also for more than two clustering solutions (unfortunately, a visual inspection mostly works for toy data sets, not for real data which is usually too messy and high-dimensional).

Roughly said: try computing the values using the formulas on page 303 in the publication you cited, instead of computing and then counting the pairs as explained in the intuition/motivation!